# Remove Qualifier For Tycho Builds

Tags: tycho

I want to have some of Tycho builds without the time stamp at the end of the version in the *Manifest.MF* (I'm trying not to use words like "release" and "standard", else people get stuck on the fact that I'm trying something that Tycho was not build to do).

I figure I have to either configure the `tycho-packaging-plugin` like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>some-special-occurrence</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <format></format><!-- can't figure out what to enter -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Maybe I could repurpose the `tycho-versions-plugin`, but I could not find any [info](https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/set-version-mojo.html) on how to prevent it from setting ".qualifier" at the end of the version.

Does anyone have an idea how to remove the qualifier for some of the Tycho builds?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this article, http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2020/02/remove-snapshot-and-qualifier-in-maven-tycho-builds/, you can use a combination of standard Maven plugins and the `tycho-versions-plugin`.

For example, you can run

```
mvn \
  build-helper:parse-version org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version \
  -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}
```

Or alternatively

```
mvn \
  versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DremoveSnapshot=true \
  org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:update-eclipse-metadata
```

The first method will first parse the current version and set some properties; with these properties you can create a version corresponding to the current one, skipping the -SNAPSHOT, and pass it to `tycho-versions-plugin`.

The second method will first remove the -SNAPSHOT from the POMs and then use `tycho-versions-plugin` to update Eclipse projects versions (removing the .qualifier).

More details can be found in the above mentioned article.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking.

If your MANIFEST.MF has a version number without a qualifier, like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: example-bundle;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0
```

then you don't have to do anything.  That is, Tycho will product artifacts with the given bundle-version, 0.1.0, with no qualifier.  You don't have to mess with the tycho-packaging-plugin.

Are you saying that you want to use a Bundle-Version with a qualifier, like 0.1.0.qualifier, in your MANIFEST.MF, but you don't want your build to strip the qualifier during the build?  If that's what you want, I think that you're going to have to submit a feature request.

Ideally, you could just provide a

```
<forceContextQualfier></forceContextQualifier>
```

or maybe

```
<forceContextQualfier>none</forceContextQualifier>
```

to indicate that you do not want the qualifier.  That is, you want something that produces the same effect as `qualifier=none` in PDE: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_version_qualifiers.htm.

But looking at https://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-packaging-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/buildversion/BuildQualifierMojo.java, it looks like forceContextQualifier is treated as a literal string.  There's no special handling for a `none` value, and a null string is always replaced with a timestamp.

The format value has to be a valid SimpleDateFormat.  Again, empty values are replaced with the default, so there's no way to request an empty or null format.

Your other option is to use the tycho-versions-plugin to set the value of your bundles and remove the qualifier.  That way, you could branch for a release, set the version to remove the qualifier, and then build.  Or maybe have the build do it on-the-fly.

But, really, I think that it would be slicker if we could just make the tycho-packaging-plugin handle a `none` forceContextQualifier value.

Comment: I think I want the opposite of what you describe: I want Snapshots with the version `1.2.3.SNAPSHOT-201604270738` and releases with the version `1.2.3` (the rest is just noise). And the `tycho-versions-plugin` always adds the qualifier no matter the configuration.

Comment: Right, the tycho-packaging-plugin always adds the qualifier.  What I was talking about toward the end was using the tycho-versions-plugin to set the version.  That is, you'd use a command like `mvn org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version -DnewVersion=1.2.0` to set the version.  After that, the version field in your pom.xml, MANIFEST.MF, etc. would no longer have a qualifier or SNAPSHOT.  Then you don't have to bother with tycho-packaging-plugin.